# Duplicate fields on the same page, on an Adobe PDF form

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms

I have a section of an Adobe PDF form which will contain a list of items, I want to be able to add as many items to this list as neccessary and for it to push the rest of the content down.

I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, is there a standard way to do this or is it just not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Propaganda would say that it is not possible, but that you could do it with XFA technology (meaning that you would have to buy LiveCycle Designer, and create a dynamic form.

It is, however, possible with PDF forms. But it may be a little bit messy, and it does require some programming. The result would require Adobe Acrobat/Reader to work (there may be a few other PDF viewers which support the necessary JavaScript objects and methods.

The key is that everything below that table which has to be pushed down has to be in form fields (either direct, using multiline, rich text-enabled text fields, or embedded as icons in button fields. Then you would need a logic which adds the needed fields, and positions the subsequent fields accordingly, and also performs pagination tasks.

It is feasible, but requires some programming.

Another approach would be the "virtual page" concept, where you keep the information for the fields in a list (aka array), and have a fixed number of lines to display it. Navigation buttons are then used to "scroll" through the information. In other words, the number of lines to display information are some kind of "window" overlaid on a much longer table.

Shameless plug: Yours truly has created several applications using either system, which are (or were) in productive use. If you happen to prefer buying over making, feel free to contact me in private.